# Tomcat not serving web app after sometime

Tags: tomcat

A spring MVC web application is hosted on Tomcat 7.0.40 on AWS server having 8 core and 32GB server. Tomcat is configured so that it will serve the web app on default root and also with context name. So both i.e http://10.20.20.120 and http://10.20.20.120/testmvc/ is valid and will serve the same webapp.

By observation it is seen that after some time tomcat stops responding on http://10.20.20.120 but if I check with http://10.20.20.120/testmvc/ then its serving best. Through app-manager I have checked all memory pool and everything is fine.

I am not able to trace what is the problem. Any suggestion that may help.

[server.xml](http://txt.do/dvajc)

Comment: Any reason why you use such an old version of Tomcat? You should create dumps of the working / no longer working process and compare them. And as you are already on AWS you should create a separate instance that you can loadtest and tune

Comment: Please make the question self contained instead of linking to other sites for text that could also be included here. Look at/post log entries and make sure that your application is actually logging events instead of swallowing them.